# Why does "if ( ! Object.property)" break if Object is undefined?

Tags: javascript

It seems silly to me that if I want to check the existence of an Object's property, I must ensure that the object exists.  If an object is undefined then all its properties should also be undefined.

So why does something like

```
if ( ! Object.property ) {
    console.log('Nope!')
} else {
    console.log('Yep!')
}
```

just break entirely if the Object is undefined?  It's annoying to nest the property verification inside an object verification.  Shouldn't this always be a legitimate if statement?

Comment: This decision seems to be in line wither other languages. In C (and derivates) you'd get a null pointer exception. Also keep in mind that the interpreter does not necessarily know what you are trying to do with the property value, it does not know that you are merely testing its existence.

Comment: @FelixKling yup, I agree.  In particular, in _most_ cases if `obj` is undefined it probably means something really bad happened.  Better to be able to trap that than have `obj.foo` silently evaluate to `undefined`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't work because looking up a property must first look up the object on which that property (might) be defined.

That's just how it is - it's a language design choice.  The designers *could* have defined that `a.b` always returns `undefined` if `a` is undefined, but they didn't.

As a short cut, you can use this syntax:

```
if (obj && typeof obj.property !== 'undefined') {
    // yep, it's defined (and not just "falsey")
} else {
    // nope
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check whether the Object itself is defined or not. You cannot reach a non-existent object's properties or variables. Otherwise your code breaks as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simplify this you can look at Ben Alman's `getObject` and `setObject`:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-getobject-plugin/

```
var myObj = {};

// Setting.
Cowboy.setObject( 'a.b.c', { d: 1, e: 2 }, myObj ); // returns a.b.c reference

// myObj is now { a: { b: { c: { d: 1, e: 2 } } } }

// Getting.
Cowboy.getObject( 'a.b.c.d', myObj ); // returns 1
Cowboy.getObject( 'a.b.c.x', myObj ); // returns undefined
Cowboy.getObject( 'a.b.c.d.x', myObj ); // returns undefined

// Testing.
Cowboy.exists( 'a.b.c.d', myObj ); // returns true
Cowboy.exists( 'a.b.c.x', myObj ); // returns false
Cowboy.exists( 'a.b.c.d.x', myObj ); // returns false

// I'm not sure why you'd want to do something like this, but it's
// certainly possible...
Cowboy.setObject( 'document.body.style.display', 'none' );
Cowboy.getObject( 'document.body.style.display' ); // returns 'none'
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking if you are actually checking for the existence of a property then best to use the following code:

```
if ( Object && "property" in Object ) {
    // defined
} else {
    // nope
}
```

The reason is that a property may exist but contain the value "undefined".

For more info check [here](http://chamnapchhorn.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/checking-property-existence-in.html)